# Zend form unneeded options in select tag

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

This is my code to generate a select element:

```
$configsForm->addElement( 
 'select',
        'option_status',
        array(
            'label'         => $this-> view -> __('Configs_Option Status'),
            'required'      => true,
            'value'         => '',
            'multiOptions'  => array('' => $this -> view -> __('Root'), 0 => 'Disabel', 1 => 'Enabel'),
        )
    );
```

And the generated select like this

```
<select name="configs[option_status]" id="configs-option_status" required="1">
    <optgroup id="configs-option_status-optgroup-options" label="options">
        <option value="" label="Select option" selected="selected">Select option</option>
        <option value="0" label="Disabel">Disabel</option>
        <option value="1" label="Enabel">Enabel</option>
    </optgroup>
    <option value="listsep" label="&lt;br /&gt;">&lt;br /&gt;</option>
    <option value="id" label="configs-option_status">configs-option_status</option>
</select>
```

It should be like this

```
    <select name="configs[option_status]" id="configs-option_status" required="1">
        <option value="" label="Select option" selected="selected">Select option</option>
        <option value="0" label="Disabel">Disabel</option>
        <option value="1" label="Enabel">Enabel</option>
</select>
```

How this can render ?

Comment: I want the select rendered as the last psudo code !

Answer (score 0):

You indeed set two options ('Disabel' and 'Enabel'), but you also set another option: `$this->view->__('Root')`. Are you sure this only returns `"Select Option"`?

Could you perform a `Zend_Debug::dump($this->view->__('Root'))` and show what the output is? I think that will help you solve your problem.

Comment: Yes I am sure even if I replace $this->view->__('Root') with 'Something'  the problem didn't solve.